# ViewPager first page scroll/slide is always slow

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have a custom created ViewPager whom adapter is filled in asynctask of main activity. The problem is first page slide event is always slow regardless how much small the slided content(or whole content) is.

How to wait till  it is certain that page sliding will be not laggy.(Or is this how jvm works?

Here my asynctask;

```
class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void>
{
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {

         categoryDbApt = new CategoryDbAdapter(getBaseContext());

         tab1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
         tab2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tab2);
         tab3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tab3);
         cvp = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.cvp);
         mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
         mainLayout.setWillNotDraw(false);
         ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
         ll.setWillNotDraw(false);
         lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
         sa = new SliderAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

         getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dashboard));

     }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),values[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

         fDashboard = new FragmentDashboard();
         fExpense = new FragmentExpense();
         fExpenseAdd = new FragmentExpenseAdd();
         fIncome = new FragmentIncome();
         fIncomeAdd = new FragmentIncomeAdd();

         fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
         fragmentList.add(fIncomeAdd);
         fragmentList.add(fIncome);
         fragmentList.add(fDashboard);
         fragmentList.add(fExpense);
         fragmentList.add(fExpenseAdd);

         cvp.setAdapter(sa);
         cvp.setCurrentItem(2);
         cvp.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

         setListeners();
         firstTimeCheck();


         return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

     }
}
```

and here my custom view pager class;

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    void smoothScrollTo(int x, int y, int velocity) {
        super.smoothScrollTo(x, y, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe viewHolder design pattern could help you !

Comment: Where to use view holder? I use fragments and set my offscreenpagelimit to 4 which covers all fragments in viewpager? Am i already loading all pages right?